# Login a facebook Test User from the client side

Tags: unit-testing, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to do some unit tests using the facebook `Test User API`.

the problem is to log a user account using the `login_url` provided by the API on the client side.

The url protocol of the `login_url` is `https` so i can't reach it with AJAX, if i reach the `login_url` on the server side, then i go back to the client side and try to connect with facebook, it doesn't log my test user account, which is normal.

So my question is, how to log in a test user on the client side ? In order to try to launch a `connect with facebook` event and observe the app's behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally use an iframe to open the link.